# What and where can I be?

Tags: riddle

> What creed you be, I can translate you
>   So you will end up something known
>   And change you from whatever state to
>   Whatever state my end is shown
>   Prepared to serve, I have my traces
>   Tied down perforce to set you free
>   Unmoving, I will take you places
>   But only when you've turned into me.

Hint 1:

> You plot, you draw, you often map me
>   You care so keenly where I go
>   And with my siblings, you'll entrap me
>   'Twixt pages so my ends you'll know

Hint 2:

> Disaster's likely if you lose me
>   Often used and often seen
>   Arrive, depart, each way you use me
>   But mostly I am inbetween

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be something like

> a road, (path, route). Another guess is something to do with travel.

What creed you be, I can translate you

So you will end up something known

And change you from whatever state to

Whatever state my end is shown.

> The road can take you anywhere no matter who you are and you will end up somewhere known. The state can be a wordplay on US states.

Prepared to serve, I have my traces

Tied down perforce to set you free

Unmoving, I will take you places

But only when you've turned into me.

> The road is unmoving but takes you places.

You plot, you draw, you keenly map me

You care so keenly where I go

And with my siblings, you'll entrap me

'Twixt pages so my ends you'll know

> This can be about a map. You plot roads, with "siblings", entrap between pages.

Disaster's likely if you lose me

Often used and often seen

Arrive, depart, each way you use me

But mostly I am inbetween

> If you lose the road you are lost, which is bad:( You arrive and depart places using the road, but it's mostly in between.

Comment: Completely right, apart from some small nuances of meaning. I am surprised that it took so long to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be:

> Google, on the internet or in the cloud?

```
What creed you be, I can translate you
```

> Google can translate text for you

```
So you will end up something known
```

> When it translates you will know what it says. It also provides a search engine where you can learn new things.

```
And change you from whatever state to
Whatever state my end is shown
```

> You transition from a state of looking something up to a state of reading whatever results google shows you.

```
Prepared to serve, I have my traces
```

> It was built to serve it's users

```
Tied down perforce to set you free
```

> It is tied down to a specific domain and it is there to set you free by helping you search and learn things

```
Unmoving, I will take you places
```

> It doesn't move, but it can take you places if you use google maps and the street view. Also, google directions can literally lead you places.

```
But only when you've turned into me.
```

> This is a stretch but if you use all of these services you have sort of turned into a googler? If you use them all of the time you have sort of locked yourself in to using their products. Because they can be so integrated in with one another it can become an inconvenience to use a different product.

Comment: Interesting answer, but not the one I was looking for (good attempt +1). I actually thought this would get answered quickly when I set it. The answer is rather more tangible than google, in the sense that it is of the physical world.